# Why I get the error: "incomplete type is not allowed" in c++?

Tags: c++

I defined a structure like this:

```
#define MAX_SIZE 100

typedef struct {
    int SqBiTNode[MAX_SIZE];
    int ElemNum;

}SqBiTree ;
```

and uses structure in the following function:

```
struct SqBiTree* createTree(int array[], int N)
{
    SqBiTree* tree = (SqBiTree*)malloc(sizeof(SqBiTree));

}
```

and I get the error:

> incomplete type in not allowed.

I wonder why?!?

Comment: are you actually using a C compiler? This code would give that error in C .

Comment: `typedef struct` is also "C" syntax.  So is the use of malloc... so all in all I think you have a "C" question not a "C++" one.

Comment: @M.M *"This code would give that error in C ."* -- It does not, at least not using C11. With both code blocks (and a suitable `#include`), a C compiler just warns about unused parameters, an unused variable, and the lack of a `return` statement. When I comment out the `typedef`,  the C compiler's errors are `unknown type name 'SqBiTree'; use 'struct' keyword to refer to the type` and `'SqBiTree' undeclared (first use in this function)`.

Comment: When I copied your code blocks into an online C++ compiler and compiled, I got `error: using typedef-name 'SqBiTree' after 'struct'`. I did not get an error about an incomplete type until I commented out the `typedef`... So perhaps delete the first code bock to get a **reproducible** example?

Comment: Your struct has no tag. You defined a type name `SqBiTree`. You did *not* define a type named `struct SqBiTree`. Also, your question title says C++, but the tag says C; which is it? Are you compiling with a C compiler or with a C++ compiler? (The code in the question is invalid in both languages, but there are different rules that could become relevant when you fix the error.)

Comment: You've declared the type `SqBiTree`, but not the type `struct SqBiTree`. Just remove the word `struct`.

Comment: @Bop You are right. When I change 'struct SqBiTree* createTree(int array[], int N)' to 'SqBiTree* createTree(int array[], int N)' the code works well. thank u

Answer (score 0):

*(Now that the question is reopened, lets make an answer from my comment)*

The code first declares a struct with no name, and a typedef alias for that struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int SqBiTNode[MAX_SIZE];
    int ElemNum;

} SqBiTree;
```

The alias name is just `SqBiTree`, not `struct SqBiTree`. Two different things!

Then the function declaration

```
struct SqBiTree* createTree(int array[], int N)
```

says that there is **also** some `struct SqBiTree` that it returns a pointer to. That's fine, it can do that. Introducing a "forward declared" struct here is OK.

The problem comes with `sizeof` that says that it hasn't seen this mysterious *other* struct, so cannot tell what size it has.

---

There  are two kinds of solutions to this.

The first is to remove the `struct` keyword from the function declaration, and just use the alias name  `SqBiTree`. This is what you would do in C.

A second, more C++-like solution, is to declare the struct without a typedef:

```
struct SqBiTree
{
    int SqBiTNode[MAX_SIZE];
    int ElemNum;
};
```

Then (in C++) you can still use only the name `SqBiTree` without having to repeat `struct` everywhere. The name lookup rules are slightly different than the original C-rules.

Comment: I still suspect the structure definition is not visible at the function definition. Testing with it visible, GCC, Clang, and MSVC all complain about the `struct SqBiTree*` before they get to `sizeof`.

Answer (score 0):

This defines an unnamed structure with an alias `SqBiTree`:

```
typedef struct  {
    int SqBiTNode[MAX_SIZE];
    int ElemNum;

} SqBiTree;
```

This defines a function called `createTree` that returns a pointer of type `struct SqBiTree*`:

```
struct SqBiTree* createTree(int array[], int N)
{
    SqBiTree* tree = (SqBiTree*)malloc(sizeof(SqBiTree));
    return tree;
}
```

But the problem is that you did not provide a definition for a struct named `SqBiTree`. Subsequently, `SqBiTree` is interpreted as `struct SqBiTree` inside your function. As a result, `sizeof` will complain that the type `SqBiTree` interpretted as `struct SqBiTree` is incomplete.

To do away with this error, simply remove `struct` from the return type of the function:

```
SqBiTree* createTree(int array[], int N)
{
    SqBiTree* tree = (SqBiTree*)malloc(sizeof(SqBiTree));
    return tree;
}
```